# SQL Select closest smaller date of another date in 2 table

Tags: mysql

i have two tables

```
Table A
pk name   a_date
1  Peter  01-01-1991
2  Paul   02-01-1991
3  John   03-01-1991

Table B
pk  b_date
A   01-01-1991
B   02-01-1991
```

What i want the result is:

```
name   a_date        b_date
Paul   02-01-1991    01-01-1991
John   03-01-1991    02-01-1991
```

Select the closest smaller date of Table B for Table A

I tried to draw the result before select

```
1  Peter  01-01-1991  A  01-01-1991
1  Peter  01-01-1991  B  02-01-1991
2  Paul   02-01-1991  A  01-01-1991
2  Paul   02-01-1991  B  02-01-1991
3  John   03-01-1991  A  01-01-1991
3  John   03-01-1991  B  02-01-1991
```

then i tried select*from A,B where a_date>b_date

but it will return like this:

```
2  Paul   02-01-1991  A  01-01-1991
3  John   03-01-1991  A  01-01-1991
3  John   03-01-1991  B  02-01-1991
```

i also tried some thing like sub-query:
where a_date = (select...);
but i think this is a wrong way.
then i think that may be distinct can solve this problem,
but i find i can't use distinct in this case.

Comment: Hi Ray, we usually expect that you post what you've tried or what your own effort was, so that it's also more clear, what your actual problem is. We like to help with certain problems, not just do your work for you.

Comment: K, i post what i have tried

Comment: I updated, because i think if i only show the problem will be more clear to others,please help if you guy don't mind, thanks

Comment: Hi - store dates as dates (i.e. using a date data type). Then get back to us.

Comment: Ooops!Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it (it assumes that dates are stored as `date` and not as strings):

```
SELECT a.name, a.date, MAX(b.date)
FROM a
JOIN b ON b.date < a.date
GROUP BY a.name, a.date
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySql 7.x you can join to a sub-query that calculates the nearest.

```
SELECT
a.*, 
b.pk as b_pk, 
b.b_date
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
     a2.pk as a_pk, 
     MAX(b2.pk) AS b_pk
    FROM TableA a2
    JOIN TableB b2 ON b2.b_date < a2.a_date
    GROUP BY a2.pk
) q ON q.a_pk = a.pk
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.pk = q.b_pk
```

A test on *rextester [here](https://rextester.com/NJTF87779)*

In MySql 8 you could use a window function for this.

```
SELECT pk, name, a_date, b_pk, b_date
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.*, 
     b.pk AS b_pk,
     b.b_date,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.pk ORDER BY b.b_date DESC) AS rn
    FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableB b ON b.b_date < a.a_date
) q
WHERE rn = 1
```

A test on *db-fiddle* [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ebEjjbEUeWi78HwYHFe7FW/0)